# User Authentication into Devise from iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am creating an application where user is going to sign in with username and password. At the back end and also for the website I am using ruby on rails where the authentication is handled by Devise. With the last edition of Devise they have depriciated the Authentication Token. I am lost in terms of how to authenticate from iOS ? Any suggestions ? How am I going to modify the gem files etc.

Comment: I meant the Devise Gem actually. and what do you mean ??? @meda

Comment: oh sorry I thought you meant Device

Answer (score 0):

See this gist from Jose Valim [Safe or Unsafe Tokens](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6)

Basically you will want to write your own auth token methods. You need to generate tokens and later compare them. You should read all of the comments, the discussion is pretty good.